# Search Function for Menu Driven Program

Tags: c++, function

I have to write a program that creates an array with 10 structures. It should let the user enter data into the array, change the contents of any element, and display all data stored in the array. Should be a menu driven user interface. I have to have a function that allows the user to search the structure array for a customers name. It should accept part of the customers name as an argument then search for an account with a name that matches it. All accounts that match should be displayed. If no account matches, a message saying so should be displayed. I have tried to write the function but I am having some trouble. I am still new to C++ and my textbook is not very helpful. The function is void findAccountInfo. When I run my program it does not prompt the user to search by name. I am not sure what I am missing. I will post my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
struct customerAccount
{
   string name, address, city, state, zip, phone;
   double account_balance;
   string last_payment_date;
};

void menu()
{
   cout << "\n MENU " << endl;
   cout << "1. Enter new customer information" << endl;
   cout << "2. Change customer information" << endl;
   cout << "3. Display all customer information" << endl;
   cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
}

void createNewAccount(struct customerAccount cus_arr[], int index)
{
    cout << "\nCustomer name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, cus_arr[index].name);
    cout << "Customer address: ";
    getline(cin, cus_arr[index].address);
    cout << "City: ";
    getline(cin, cus_arr[index].city);
    cout << "State: ";
    getline(cin, cus_arr[index].state);
    cout << "ZIP Code: ";
    getline(cin, cus_arr[index].zip);
    cout << "Telephone: ";
    getline(cin, cus_arr[index].phone);
    cout << "Account balance: ";
    cin >> cus_arr[index].account_balance;
    if (cus_arr[index].account_balance < 0) 
    {
        cout << "Account balance cannot be negative. Please re-enter account balance: " << endl;
        cin >> cus_arr[index].account_balance;
    }
    cout << "Date of last payment: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, cus_arr[index].last_payment_date);
    cout << "You have entered information for customer";
    cout << " number " << index << endl;
}

void changeAccountInfo(struct customerAccount cus_arr[], int cus_num, int size)
{
    if (cus_num < 0 || cus_num > size)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Customer Number!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nCustomer name: "  << cus_arr[cus_num].name << endl;
        cout << "Customer address: " << cus_arr[cus_num].address << endl;
        cout << "City: " << cus_arr[cus_num].city << endl;
        cout << "State: " << cus_arr[cus_num].state << endl;
        cout << "ZIP Code: " << cus_arr[cus_num].zip << endl;
        cout << "Telephone: " << cus_arr[cus_num].phone << endl;
        cout << "Account balnace: " << cus_arr[cus_num].account_balance << endl;
        cout << "Date of last payment: " << cus_arr[cus_num].last_payment_date << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Edit the account information of the ";
        cout << "customer " << cus_num << endl;

        cout << "\nCustomer name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, cus_arr[cus_num].name);
        cout << "Customer address: ";
        getline(cin, cus_arr[cus_num].address);
        cout << "City: ";
        getline(cin, cus_arr[cus_num].city);
        cout << "State: ";
        getline(cin, cus_arr[cus_num].state);
        cout << "ZIP Code: ";
        getline(cin, cus_arr[cus_num].zip);
        cout << "Telephone: ";
        getline(cin, cus_arr[cus_num].phone);
        cout << "Account balance: ";
        cin >> cus_arr[cus_num].account_balance;
        cout << "Date of last payment: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, cus_arr[cus_num].last_payment_date);
        cout << "Account information for customer " <<   cus_num << " has been updated." << endl;
    }
}

void displayAccountInfo(struct customerAccount cus_arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       cout << "\nCustomer name: " << cus_arr[i].name << endl;
       cout << "Customer address: " << cus_arr[i].address << endl;
       cout << "City: " << cus_arr[i].city << endl;
       cout << "State: " << cus_arr[i].state << endl;
       cout << "ZIP Code: " << cus_arr[i].zip << endl;
       cout << "Telephone: " << cus_arr[i].phone << endl;
       cout << "Account balnace: " << cus_arr[i].account_balance << endl;
       cout << "Date of last payment: " << cus_arr[i].last_payment_date << endl;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\nPress enter to continue..." << endl;
    if (cin.get() == '\n')
    {
       return;
    }
}
```

This is the function I am having problems with

```
void findAccountInfo(struct customerAccount cus_arr[], customerAccount cus_acc_arr) 
{
    int index = 0;
    int cuss_num = 0;
    string searchName = "";
    bool found = false;
    cout << "Enter a name (partial or full) to search for: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, searchName);
    for (index = 0; index < cuss_num; index++) 
    {
        if (cus_arr[index].name.find(searchName) != string::npos) 
        {
            cout << "Account Name:" << (index + 1) << "" << cus_arr[index].name << "\n";
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found == true) 
    {
        cout << "Enter account id:";
        cin >> cuss_num;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "This name was not found in the database";
    }
    return;
}
```

Rest of my code

```
int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    int i, f = 0;
    i = 0;
    int cus_num = 0;
    customerAccount cus_acc_arr[20];
    menu();
    cout << "Please enter a choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    while (true)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                createNewAccount(cus_acc_arr, i);
                i++;
            break;

            case 2:
                cout << "Enter a customer number to ";
                cout << "change the account ";
                cout << "information:" << endl;
                cout << "Customer number: ";
                cin >> cus_num;
                changeAccountInfo(cus_acc_arr, cus_num, i);
            break;

            case 3:
                displayAccountInfo(cus_acc_arr, i);
            break;

            case 4:
                system("pause");
                return 0;

            default:
                f = 1;
                cout << "Please enter a valid choice ";
                cout << "between 1, 2, 3, and 4:" << endl;
                menu();
                cout << "Please enter a choice: ";
                cin >> choice;
          }

          if (f != 1)
          {
              menu();
              cout << "Please enter a choice: ";
              cin >> choice;
          }
      }
      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should remove those comments from your code, get rid of the double spacing, and use coherent indentation.  There is no need to scroll down 3 screen-worths of code because of excessive commenting.

Comment: I took the time to edit your code.  Note that this is how code should be presented here, and not only that, how you should strive to format your code, commented or not.

Comment: [Here is the full shared code that compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/777c55a97d5fe747).

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I clicked on the link but it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: [Please try this link for the full code](https://www.ideone.com/UEg3lE)

Comment: I have checked the code but my problem is still the same. It should prompt the user at the beginning of the program to enter a name partial or full to search for. The program should then search for the name and find it or let the user know it does not exist.

Comment: I did not change any code except to have it formatted so that it can be read.  Your original code was not readable.  Have you used the debugger, and if not, please [read this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)